# iPhone application crash because -[NSMutableArray addObjectsFromArray:]: array argument is not an NSArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I want to search from `UITableView` when I am trying to add searched objects from one array to another array ,my application get crash.Here is my code in which I trying to add objects from one array to another.
`searchedContactsFromTable` is `NSMutableArray`.in which I am getting 200 objects.

```
    NSMutableArray *searchArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (NSDictionary *dictionary in searchedContactsFromTable)
{
       NSArray *array = [dictionary objectForKey:@"fullName"];
       [searchArray addObjectsFromArray:array];

}
```

How can I add array?

Comment: Which line it's crashing and what s the crash log?

Comment: can we have a look at the crash log .?

Comment: try NSLog(@"%@",[array class]) and see what it gives you. From the error you're getting, I'm guessing it's not actually an array.

Comment: Ankit Srivastava -[NSMutableArray addObjectsFromArray:]: array argument is not an NSArray

Comment: -rdelmar you are right.I am getting __NSCFString. Now what can I do??

Comment: Try :  NSString *array = [dictionary objectForKey:@"fullName"];
       [searchArray addObject:array];

Comment: How should I know? I don't know what you're trying to accomplish, and have no idea what your data structure is.

Comment: @newDev : Your Problem is Solved.Just check my answer !!!

Comment: Thanks, Its not crashing now, Its work with [searchArray addObject:array]; - Rushi

Comment: @newDev : i'll write the answer. You can accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change :

```
NSMutableArray *searchArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (NSDictionary *dictionary in searchedContactsFromTable)
{
       NSString *array = [dictionary objectForKey:@"fullName"];
       [searchArray addObject:array];

}
```

As array variable which you are getting here is not a array but it's a string.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your `searchedContactsFromTable` is like :

```
searchedContactsFromTable :: (
        {
        fullName =         {
            fName = Abc;
            lName = Ghi;
            mName = Def;
        };
    }
)
```

and you want Output like this :

```
searchArray :: (
        (
        Abc,
        Ghi,
        Def
    )
)
```

Your Code should be :

```
    NSMutableArray *searchArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (NSDictionary *dictionary in searchedContactsFromTable)
    {
        NSDictionary *dict = [dictionary objectForKey:@"fullName"];
        [searchArray addObject:[dict allValues]];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableArray *searchArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (NSDictionary *dictionary in searchedContactsFromTable)
{
       NSMutableArray *array = (NSMutableArray *)[[[dictionary objectForKey:@"fullName"] miutableCopy];
       [searchArray addObjectsFromArray:array];

}
```

Comment: Thanks Amit Battan, but still its crashing :(

Comment: can you post the crash log or reason why it crashing. Are you sure `[dictionary objectForKey:@"fullName"]` is a Array?  it seems that `[dictionary objectForKey:@"fullName"]` is a string

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *searchArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (NSDictionary *dictionary in searchedContactsFromTable)
{
       [array addObject:[dictionary objectForKey:@"fullName"]];
       [searchArray addObjectsFromArray:array];

}
```

Comment: Hi newDev, Please let me know if any option worked for you :)